# Where to find .NET version usage statistics?

Tags: .net, statistics, version

There are some technologies like LINQ and WPF which are nice, but installation of .NET 3.5 is still slow procedure. It's important to understand - among Windows users how many of them have .NET 3.5 installed?

Is there any good up to date stats gathered about .NET **Version** availability/usage?
I've searched a lot, but can't find.

**Update:** .NET version IS present in web-agent strings for FF and IE at least. So there SHOULD be somebody who have that information. **Anyone with access to really large web-site logs?**

**Update 2:** I also understand Vista means that user have 3.5, but XP is still dominating the market.

Comment: "Anyone with access to really large web-site logs?" Uhhh, yeah, the StackOverflow admins? :-)

Comment: That would be nice, but stackoverflow is not general audience site - developers are probably using latest version of .NET mostly.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the stats here: http://www.statowl.com/microsoft_dotnet.php

Comment: This site stopped working around 2013 :(

Answer (score 2):

[Scott Wiltamuth's Visual Studio blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/scottwil/archive/2005/03/09/391199.aspx) contains some data for 2005. Obviously won't help with 3.5 data, but may be a start.

I also found this from a forum post dated 2008:

> For example, from analyzing website's logs I found that of all visitors who 
>   has Vista/XP/2000 only 51% have .NET 2.0 
>   and only 13% have  .NET 3.0

There seems to be a real shortage of valuable data like this. I was asked a week ago what percentage of Vista installations were 64-bit and all I could find was [this article](http://itmanagement.earthweb.com/entdev/article.php/11070_3782171_1/Windows-7-May-Trigger-64-bit-OS-Adoption.htm) that basically said the data wasn't available.

Answer (score 2):

There is another [statistics dated January 2010](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowManyPCsInTheWorldHaveTheNETFrameworkInstalled.aspx), published by Scott Hanselman.

Answer (score 2):

[January and April 2011 statistics](http://www.nemo-docs.com/blog/usage-statistics/) from Nemo Documents.  [Stat Owl](http://www.statowl.com/microsoft_dotnet.php) has some data as well.